# LinearLayout defStyle on Android SDK 10?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm writing a class that extends LinearLayout from the Android library. In the class constructor I used the LinearyLayout constructor LinearLayout(Context context,AttributeSet attrs, int defStyles) introduced only in SDK 11. The problem is that I am trying to make the application run on Android 2.3.3 which runs SDK 10. I have tried introducing a check similar to this:

```
public SView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    } else {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    setupView(context);
}
```

But the problem persists because **super** must be on the first line. Another issue is the functionality that defStyle provides is not substituted.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use two separate XML files.  One that uses `SView`, and one that uses an alternative that is "2.3.3 friendly".

You would do your check before setting your activity or fragment's layout.  Like this:

```
   int layoutId = R.layout.fancy_stuff;
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        layoutId = R.layout.boring_stuff;
   }
   setContentView(layoutId);
```

`fancy_stuff` would refer to your `SView`, and `boring_stuff` would refer to your SDK 10 stuff.